# New desktop build, Which I7 CPU to choose

Tags: processor, gaming, desktop

I've started making a list for a new build I'm doing, since my current desktop is starting to get some problems. But getting to the CPU, I'm really split about the choice of CPU. I've decided that I'm most likely gonna go with an Intel core I7, but I can't decide if I should go with the 10th or 11th gen, and I also can't decide if I should go with the K or KF model. As far as I understand the only diffrence between K and KF is that K has integrated Graphics and KF doesn't, but then KF is slightly cheaper.

Is it just a waste of money to buy K instead of KF since the build will include a GPU? And is the difference between 10th and 11th gen, enough to make up the difference in price?

The choices are between:

- Intel core I7-11700K
- Intel core I7-11700KF
- Intel core I7-10700K
- Intel core I7-10700KF

For context, the rest of the build looks something like this:

- MSI MPG Z490 Gaming Plus
- Asus GeForce RTX 3080 TI TUF OC
- Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4-3600 C18 2x16GB
- Samsung 980 PRO SSD 1TB
- (A 1000Watt power supply, atleast 80+ gold certified)

I mostly use my desktop for gaming, but from time to time, I also do some video editing and rendering, 3D modeling, some programming, and VR gaming.

I have all these parts available at my local shop so that isn't a problem, but would also love to hear peoples suggestions. All input is greatly appreciated, I'd love to learn something new, Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine but I would suggest you to go for an AMD CPU instead of the intel one.

AMD competes toe to toe with intel in most games and surpasses intel in a lot of games as well. Also AMD is better oriented for a professional workflow like rendering etc. The 5800x even has a lower TDP than the intel 11700k.
Also make sure that the cooling is sufficient, you would probably need an AIO for the same if not a good dual tower air cooler like the Noctua NH D15 or bequiet Dark Rock Pro.

If you are absolutely going with intel then I don't find much merit in getting the 11th gen over 10th gen for games. But in cases of workflows like rendering etc 11th gen would give a bit of an advantage. KF is a better choice if you have a GPU available at hand, but if you dont then you wont be able to run your PC until you get a GPU.

Also I am not saying this as an AMD fanboy I already have the 10700k, but the heat this processor gives out is insane.